# Load GoogleMaps Script with Ajax

Tags: javascript, ajax, google-maps-api-3

I am trying to load this view with AJAX, I know tha initialize function don't run correctly because the window's load event start before I load the view with AJAX, but I don't find the way to do that without this:

```
google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
```

Sorry for my English.

```
function initialize() {

    var myLatlng = new google.maps.LatLng(1000,1000);
    var mapOptions = {

        zoom: 16,
        center: myLatlng,
        mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP

    }

    var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map-canvas'), mapOptions);
    var marker = new google.maps.Marker({

        position: myLatlng,
        map: map,
        title: 'Aqui estamos!'

    });

}
initialize()//Don`t work
google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
```

Comment: Thanks Steve for your answer, that work. But I don't know how, anyone can explain me why I must to create the script element dynamically?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/map-simple-async :

```js
function initialize() {
  var mapOptions = {
    zoom: 8,
    center: new google.maps.LatLng(-34.397, 150.644)
  };

  var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map-canvas'),
      mapOptions);
}

function loadScript() {
  var script = document.createElement('script');
  script.type = 'text/javascript';
  script.src = 'https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?v=3.exp&sensor=false&' +
      'callback=initialize';
  document.body.appendChild(script);
}

window.onload = loadScript;
```